# power BI data to display

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have tried all I c[PowerBi issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emqqz.jpg)an and cannot seem to make it work. Please I need help. I am trying to get the data for previous qtr and last 2 qtrs but cannot get it right. see formula below. but it gives me total. thanks

```
Last 1 qtr = CALCULATE([Total Sales], DATEADD(DimDate[FullDateAlternateKey], -1, QUARTER))
Last 2 qtr = CALCULATE([Total Sales] , DATEADD(DimDate[FullDateAlternateKey], -2, QUARTER))
```

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has a built in function to calculate aggregated values for Previous Quarter with below syntax-

```
PREVIOUSQUARTER(<dates>)
```

For more details, your can check Microsoft's official documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousquarter-function-dax)

Some additional help you will get [Here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Count-previous-quarter/td-p/822108)